# How to change button's Image on clicking it in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Confession: I have been through every possible link I could find, but unfortunately none work for me.

I am creating buttons dynamically. When a button is selected, it should change the color of the selected button and the rest should remain the default color. This way, the user can identify which button is selected.

Suppose there are 3 buttons: all blue in color, and when I select the first one, it should change to white and other two should remain blue. When I select the second, the first one should go back to blue and the second should now be white.

**btnCounts** data I am fetching from server and would vary.

```
  -(void)createButtons{
    for (int i=0; i<btnCounts; i++) {
       UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
       [btn setTag:i];
       [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(xVal, 0, width/btnCounts, 40)];
      // [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
       [btn setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       [scrV addSubview:btn];
       xVal += self.view.frame.size.width/btnCounts+1;
     }
 }
```

Now, in **btnClicked:** method I am passing the button as a parameter, so that I can use selected button.

```
 -(void)btnClicked:(UIButton *)button
 {
     int tag = (int)button.tag;
     //...
 }
```

Please help me to find what I am missing here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance `UIButton` variable to house the selected button so that you can deselect it when the next button is tapped. If you only pass the currently-tapped button to your `btnClicked:` method, you won't know which button to deselect (if any).

```
@implementation ClassName {
    UIButton *previousButton;
}

...

- (void)btnClicked:(UIButton *)button
{
    if(previousButton)
        [previousButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    previousButton = button;

    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    // do whatever else you need to do here
}
```

Comment: Aha! Perfect, thank you so much, for further seeker, just need to comment these two lines [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected]; then use @Stonz2 code

Comment: It would be great if you could brief the code? And any idea on how to keep first button image different than others by default, I am displaying a default view before any button get clicked, so it should look like first button is selected.

Comment: @mavericks If you always want it to be the first, then in your loop that creates the buttons, add a conditional `if(i == 0)` and do what you need to do there.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to store selected button in temporary object.

Create button in interface(.h) file:

```
UIButton *selectedButton;
```

Than add following line in `-(void)createButtons` method before for loop.

```
selectedButton = nil;

for() {...}
```

Here `selectedButton` is set to nil because initially none of the buttons are selected.

And finally replace your `-(void)btnClicked:(UIButton *)button` method with following method.

```
-(void)btnClicked:(UIButton *)button {
    if(selectedButton) {
        selectedButton.selected = NO;
    }

    button.selected = YES;
    selectedButton = button;
}
```

If you want to make any button initially selected  than assign that button to `selectedButton` like in btnClicked method.